# 403 Forbidden on ESPv2, GKE AutoPilot, WIF

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, endpoint, grpc-python, workload-identity

I'm following the [Getting started with Endpoints for GKE with ESPv2](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-kubernetes-engine-espv2). I'm using Workload Identity Federation and Autopilot on the GKE cluster.

I've been running into the error:

`F0110 03:46:24.304229       8 server.go:54] fail to initialize config manager: http call to GET https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/name:bookstore.endpoints.<project>.cloud.goog/rollouts?filter=status=SUCCESS returns not 200 OK: 403 Forbidden`

Which ultimately leads to a transport failure error and shut down of the Pod.

My first step was to investigate permission issues, but I could really use some outside perspective on this as I've been going around in circles on this.

Here's my config:

```
>> gcloud container clusters describe $GKE_CLUSTER_NAME \
--zone=$GKE_CLUSTER_ZONE \
--format='value[delimiter="\n"](nodePools[].config.oauthScopes)'
```

```
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append']
```

```
>> gcloud container clusters describe $GKE_CLUSTER_NAME \
--zone=$GKE_CLUSTER_ZONE \
--format='value[delimiter="\n"](nodePools[].config.serviceAccount)'
default
default
```

---

Service-Account-Name: test-espv2

Roles

```
Cloud Trace Agent
Owner
Service Account Token Creator
Service Account User
Service Controller
Workload Identity User
```

---

I've associated the WIF svc-act with the Cluster with the following yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: test-espv2@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  name: test-espv2
  namespace: eventing
```

And then I've associated the pod with the `test-espv2` svc-act

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: esp-grpc-bookstore
  namespace: eventing
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: esp-grpc-bookstore
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: esp-grpc-bookstore
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: test-espv2
```

---

Since the `gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:2` is limited,
I created a test container and deployed it into the same `eventing` namespace.

Within the container, I'm able to retrieve the endpoint service config with the following command:

```
curl --fail -o "service.json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
 "https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/${SERVICE}/configs/${CONFIG_ID}?view=FULL"
```

And also within the container, I'm running as the impersonated service account, tested with:

```
curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/
```

Are there any other tests I can run to help me debug this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There are *so* many steps with Cloud Endpoints. I feel your pain! I've scripted my (gRPC-based Cloud Run) deployment partly because I always forget at least one step! Did you `gcloud services enable` your service? Did you do the `gcloud endpoints services add-iam-policy-binding` step?

Comment: > `gcloud services list | grep -e endpoints -e service`

bookstore.endpoints.<project>.cloud.goog  Bookstore gRPC API
endpoints.googleapis.com                                 Google Cloud Endpoints
servicecontrol.googleapis.com                          Service Control API
servicemanagement.googleapis.com                Service Management API

> `gcloud endpoints services get-iam-policy bookstore.endpoints.<project>.cloud.goog`

bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:test-espv2@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/servicemanagement.serviceController
etag: BwXUzTf4Khc=

Comment: Have you run the `gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding` command documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#authenticating_to) in step 7? It is needed to allow the Kubernetes service account to impersonate the Google service account.

Comment: @DazWilkin apologies for the formatting, came out weird. In short I've verified that I have completed those steps, still the same issue. Your scripted deployment, is it on public github?

Comment: No worries. I don't see anything obviously wrong but, as I said, it's such a convoluted process that it's easy to miss something. I'm using gRPC on Cloud Run and no WIF so my scenario is quite different to yours.

Comment: I would suggest you enable [Data Access audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/audit-logging) and see what is the reason you are getting the error in the logs. If not, can you check your GKE configuration if it is working perfectly or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured out the issue. It was in 2 parts.

1. Redeployment of app, paying special attention and verification of the `kubectl annotate serviceaccount` commands

   - add-iam-policy-binding for both serviceController and cloudtrace.agent
   - omitting `nodeSelector: iam.gke.io/gke-metadata-server-enabled: "true"`  due to Autopilot

Doing this enabled a successful kube deployment as displayed by the logs.

Next error I had was

```
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
```

2. This was fixed by turning my attention back to my Kube cluster.
   Looking through the events in my ingress service, since I was in a shared-vpc and my security policies only allowed firewall management from the host project, the deployment was failing to update the firewall rules.

Manually provisioning them, as shown here :

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#manually_provision_firewall_rules_from_the_host_project

solved my issues.

Answer (score 1):

Around debugging - I've often found my mistakes by following one of the other methods/programming languages in the Google tutorials.

Have you looked at the [OpenAPI notes](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine-espv2) and tried to follow along?